# Plotting an Ellipse after an Ellipse Fit

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, regression

I wonder if someone can assist my understanding as I'm a bit stumped with this...

I have taken the following (x,y) data which lies roughly on an ellipse:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0.000234491 & 6855810 \\
0.341848914 & 6856102 \\
0.640414035 & 6874479 \\
0.863239913 & 6908917 \\
0.985101853 & 6955917 \\
0.984332848 & 7006108 \\
0.867029832 & 7056389 \\
0.639589281 & 7100398 \\
0.333714725 & 7134165 \\
0.002441713 & 7147290 \\
-0.342779385 & 7146184 \\
-0.655455534 & 7137322 \\
-0.641777617 & 7136216 \\
-0.860267224 & 7116067 \\
-0.983690351 & 7072538 \\
-0.983008472 & 7021338 \\
-0.869967818 & 6973290 \\
-0.630288354 & 6923542 \\
-0.348927005 & 6889049 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If you were to plot this in Mathcad you will get the following:

[image: Plot of Ellipse Points]

Now, it is my intention to perform a best fit on these points to give me an equation of an ellipse.  What I have done is to implement the algorithm based upon this paper - http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/WSCG98.pdf

The fit is against the following equation:

$ ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 +dx + ey + f = 0 $

Now, the fitting algorithm gives me the following co-effiecients:

$$
\begin{align}
& a=0.99999999999513789 \\
& b=0.0000031183817557930131 \\
& c=0.000000000045507950324787355 \\
& d=-21.87186231583247 \\
& e=-0.00063773270848852459 \\
& f=2233.2983593954009 \\
\end{align}
$$

With a center of $ (0.0116,7006431) $ which looks ok to me.

Now, here is the bit I'm stumped...

I just expected to be able to plot an ellipse centered on $ (0.0116,7006431) $ that best fits the data points above.  I assumed I could feed my original (x,y) data into :

$ F(x,y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 +dx + ey + f $

And this would give me data points lying on an ellipse which I could superimpose onto the original data.

What I get is as follows:

[image: Fit values]

I guess my question is - what am I misunderstanding here?  How do I use the output from the fit (a, b, ... f) to plot an ellipse which is centered on $ (0.0116,7006431) $ and can be superimposed onto the original data?

Many thanks in advanced for any pointers/assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a function $F(x,y)$, that would imply that you have some 3d object. you have an expression [$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.99999999999513789x%5E2%2b0.0000031183817557930131xy%2b0.000000000045507950324787355y%5E2%E2%88%9221.87186231583247x%E2%88%920.00063773270848852459y%2b2233.2983593954009=0).

You need to plug in $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f$ for $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f$, and then, for each coordinate pair you want plug in either x or y, and then solve for the variable you didn't plug in.

What you did was make a form of error plot.

Comment: Ahh ok...  I was being daft!

Comment: happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I have done is to determine the y value from the x:

[image: y(x)]

I have then determined y from x and plotted on top of the original data (blue points are the fitted values, red are the original):

[image]

Thankyou for your assistance.

Comment: I have a problem with the reconstruction of the procedure in the mentioned article. In (eq 28) there is the explicite condition that $a_1^T \cdot C_1 \cdot a_1 = 1$ which requires a correction by division by about $288443.686$ and then the first resulting coefficient $a \ne 1$. However, to reproduce your data/function, it seems to be required that $a=1$ instead, such that the condition involving $C_1$ does ***not*** hold. What's going on here?