# Fitting and Ellipse to a set of data points in Mathcad.

Tags: conic-sections, regression, mathcad

I would like to fit an ellipse to a set of data points in Mathcad and afterwards plot it.
Searching the net, I stumbled on to Mike Shaw's post, which answers 75% of my question:
See [Plotting an Ellipse after an Ellipse Fit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793289/plotting-an-ellipse-after-an-ellipse-fit)

Could someone enlighten me how to determine the co-effiecients and centre of the ellipse, in Mathcad, using the fitting algorithm; this for formula: $ax^2 +bxy+cy^2 +dx+ey+f=0$

Thanks in advance,

Simon

Comment: If you want an ellipse (as opposed to some other type of conic section curve), then you have to constrain the coefficients to ensure this.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the mathematics [in this document](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/LeastSquaresFitting.pdf), along with several other fitting techniques. The same web site has code to do the fitting. I have never used the fitting code, but I have used other code from this site, and found it be of very high quality.

Mike Shaw's post says he used the algorithm decribed in [this paper](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/WSCG98.pdf), which also looks very good, to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I was under the assumption that Mike used some sort of fitting functionality within MathCAD like "genfit" with just $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$ and the data points as input. Enlightened by your answer I successfully implemented the algorithm of the paper.

Comment: Simon - Hi there.  I implemented the algorithm from the paper in the Link using the Programming Tools within Mathcad.  If I'm honest I didn't even think about Genfit, etc as I was wanting to write some C libraries to do it :-)